# Swift: post only specific codable objects

Tags: swift, xcode, api, codable

I am trying to work out how to upload only certain values via a put request. Essentially, I have an app whereby when the user accesses a specific screen, there are a bunch of fields, some of whose values will be pre-populated from an API (precisely which values are already populated is unpredictable). Any blank fields are editable and the user can put their own values in and upload them via a put request. However, I only want to upload new values (that were essentially 'nil' in the original API response). I do not want to override the values that came with the initial response and 're-upload' them. Here is the codable struct which essentially represents the body of the request:

```
struct UpdateRequest: Codable {

        let total: Double?
        let discrep: Double?
        let percent: Double?
        let pre: Double?
        let target: Double?
        let req: Double?
        let dep: Double?
    }
```

So all values are optional.

Here is my update method which is called once the user has completed the 'blanks' and pressed a specific button:

```
    func updateVals() {
        let args = ["id": viewModel.id]

        guard let body = convertValues() else { return }

        API.client.post(.order, with: args, using: .put, posting: body, expecting: MessageResponse.self) { (success, response) in

            switch success {
            case .failure:
                DispatchQueue.asyncMain {
                    let viewController = WarningViewController.detailsUpdatedFailure()
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.asyncMain {
                    let viewController = WarningViewController.detailsUpdatedSuccess()
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is convertedValues() :

```
func convertValues() -> UpdateRequest? {

      // In here I have a bunch of logic to convert values to specific units which is not relevant to this question

    {

        return UpdateRequest(
           total: convertedTotal
           discrep: convertedDiscrep
           percent: convertedPercent
           pre: convertedPre
           target: convertedTarget
           req: convertedReq
           dep: convertedDep
           )
    }

    return nil
}
```

However, if 'total' for example was in the initial API response I do not want to upload it to this request - as this end point is essentially the same as the 'get' endpoint from which I am populating these initial values.

Obviously I can write logic to check if the values were in the response, but how can I only upload new values to this UpdateRequest without uploading 'nil' values for the ones I don't need?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to override `encode(to:)` in `UpdateRequest` and use `encodeIfPresent` since that method will not include values that are nil.

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(total, forKey: .total)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(discrep, forKey: .discrep)
    //... and so on
}
```

Example with only `total` set

```
let req = UpdateRequest(total: 123.5, discrep: nil, percent: nil, pre: nil, target: nil, req: nil, dep: nil)

do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(req)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

outputs

> Optional("{\"total\":123.5}")